# How to wrap "expanded variadic template parameters"?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

C++03 allows to create template class which inheritances from template parameters:

```cpp
// c++03 

struct NullType {};

template <class T0, class T1 = NullType, class T2 = NullType>
class Collector : public T0, public T1, public T2
{
};

template <class T0, class T1>
class Collector<T0, T1, NullType> : public T0, public T1
{
};

template <class T0>
class Collector<T0, NullType, NullType> : public T0
{
};
```

So

```cpp
typedef Collector<A, B, C> X;
```

eqeals to

```cpp
class X: public A, public B, public C {};
```

C++11 allows do it easier:

```cpp
// variadic templates - great thing!
template <class ... Classes>
class C11_Collector :
    public Classes ...
{
};
```

Wrapping collector must wraps template parameters before inheritence:

```cpp
template <template <class> class Wrap, class T0, class T1 = NullType, class T2 = NullType>
class Wrapping_Collector : public Wrap<T0>, public Wrap<T1>, public Wrap<T2>
{
};

template <template <class> class Wrap, class T0, class T1>
class Wrapping_Collector<Wrap, T0, T1, NullType> : public Wrap<T0>, public Wrap<T1>
{
};

template <template <class> class Wrap, class T0>
class Wrapping_Collector<Wrap, T0, NullType, NullType> : public Wrap<T0>
{
};
```

So

```cpp
typedef Wrapping_Collector<W, A, B> X;
```

eqeals to

```cpp
class X: public W<A>, public W<B> {};
```

How implement Wrapping_Collector in more easer way by c++11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible to just enforce `Wrap<NullType>` to be an empty class? Then you could just directly use

```
template <template <typename> class Wrap, typename... Types>
class Wrapping_Collector : public Wrap<Types>... {
   //...
};
```

---

Alternatively, if a double-inheritance chain instead of direct multi-inheritance is fine, you could make `Wrapping_Collector<Wrap, A, B...>` derive from both `Wrapping_Collector<Wrap, B...>` and `Wrap<A>`:

```
template <template <typename> class Wrap, typename... Types>
class Wrapping_Collector;

// The normal case
template <template <typename> class Wrap, typename Head, typename... Rest>
class Wrapping_Collector<Wrap, Head, Rest...>
    : public Wrapping_Collector<Wrap, Rest...>, Wrap<Head>
{
    //...
};

// Ignore on NullType
template <template <typename> class Wrap, typename... Rest>
class Wrapping_Collector<Wrap, NullType, Rest...>
    : public Wrapping_Collector<Wrap, Rest...>
{
    //...
};

// Base case
template <template <typename> class Wrap>
class Wrapping_Collector<Wrap> {};
```

Comment: I do not understand why `Wrap<NullType>` is even necessary. Did not `NullType` exist in the first place due to absence of variadic templates in C++03?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would do this in C++11:

```
// variadic templates - great thing!
template <template <class> class Wrap, class... Classes>
class C11_Wrapping_Collector : public Wrap<Classes>... 
{
};
```